# Have got married

Tags: future-time

> Have you got married
>   They have got married

Are these sentences used to ask someone whether he/she or they have decided to get married on a particular date, are they ready for it, or something else?

Comment: _Get married_ is a fairly colloquial way of saying _go through a wedding ceremony_, so you would only say "They have got married" _after_ the ceremony. You might ask an old acquaintance "Have you got married [since I saw you last]?"

Comment: Are these sentences used on another occasions?

Comment: You would normally ask "Are you married?" if you wanted to ask about someone's marital status, but you might possibly ask "Have you and your fiancée got married yet?" meaning "Has the wedding already taken place?" You would only say "They have got married" if the wedding was fairly recent.

Comment: (idiomatic) To have (a future engagement).
I can't stay, I've got school tomorrow morning.(Please describe its meaning ,can we imply this rule for the above two sentences)

Comment: This is an entirely different use of 'got' - it's 'I've got' as a colloquial equivalent to 'I have'. To 'get married' is the same as to 'get fired from your job' or to 'get your hair cut' - to have someone perform an action in relation to you.